# Clickhouse toYYYYMM gives diffent month of the date

Tags: clickhouse, dbeaver

Running query in clickhouse, `select log_time, toYYYYMM(log_time), toYYYYMMDD(log_time)  from new_log limit 1` and it outputs `'2024-02-29 16:00:00', '202403','20240301'`. The date month is Febrary but toYYYYMM gives the March. btw: My timezone is +8.

[image]

`2024/03/21`:

Runs the above `select` statement in clickhouse-client and it gives different output.
[image]

So the problem should be related with client tool **dbeaver**.
Thanks @vladimir for your answer.

Comment: According to the docs for toYYYYMM, you can pass in an optional timezone as the second parameter. Does doing that get you the correct result? https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions#toyyyymm

Comment: Check the session's timezone - `SELECT timezone()`. Is it UTC?

Comment: Which timezone is used for `log_time` - UTC or 'Etc/GMT+8'?

Comment: @vladimir select timezone in clickhouse returns `Asia/Shanghai`. Timezone `log_time` used  is the system timezone since clickhouse uses os timezone and timedatectl returns `Asia/Shanghai` too.

Comment: could you check that the server's timezone is not redefined in [<timezone>](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#timezone) and try to run this query in `clickhouse-client` (the tool that you use can impact timezone (check it config)).

Comment: <timezone> in /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml is commented. Running `select timezone()` in clickhouse-client returns `Asia/Shanghai` too, but `clickhouse-client` gives `2024-03-01` instead of `2023-02-29`. I think it is caused by the client tool (dbeaver).